# magento 2 slider as well as mageplaza banner slider won't show in my custom theme

Tags: slider, banner-slider

I had installed [mageplaza banner slider](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider) followed their guide. but the slider wont show in my custom theme. this happen as well with the default magento 2 slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the css file when I change the direction of the contents from right to left (the page is in Arabic)

```
body{
  direction: rtl !important;
}
```

if comment this part of code

```
body{
  //direction: rtl !important;
}
```

the problem got fixed. but Iam not sure what is the cause.